# Statement outside watch not run

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new to Node.JS and I'm trying to run an example in the book [Node.js The Right Way](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1937785734). The following code is saved in a file called *watcher.js* and the text file *target.txt* is in the same directory.

```
const fs = require('fs');
fs.watch('target.txt',function(){
    console.log("File 'target.txt' just changed!");
});
console.log("Now watching target.txt for changes...");
```

When I run the file with the `node` command, the last line of the file, which should naturally be output first, is never seen. The log statement inside `fs.watch()` works fine and outputs the message every time the file changes.

There is a big gap between my version of Node.js (v6.11.0) and the one in the book (v0.10.20).

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: How are you running your app, are you just doing `node watcher.js`? The above code should work without any issues on v6.11.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested, your code works perfectly on node v7.1:
[image]

Comment: I have no idea but it just started working! Thanks for the reply.